# Jupyter and aarch64

Tags: python, docker, arm, jupyter, arm64

What i have: NanoPi Neo2 (Allwinner A5 (arm v8 x64) processor, 512mb ram)
What I did:

1. `apt-get install docker*`
2. `docker pull konmeo/jupyter` (got [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/konmeo/jupyter/))
3. `docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8888 4fdcd3a6ff59`
   it said `[C 19:38:32.851 NotebookApp] Running as root is not recommended. Use --allow-root to bypass.`
4. I runned `docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8888 4fdcd3a6ff59 /usr/bin/jupyter notebook --allow-root`, everything in docker is okay

   ```
   [W 19:40:36.237 NotebookApp] server_extensions is deprecated, use nbserver_extensions
   [I 19:40:36.287 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
   [I 19:40:39.827 NotebookApp] hide_code: Attempting to load hid_code export handler extensions.
   [I 19:40:39.839 NotebookApp] hide_code: Hide_code export handler extensions loaded.
   [I 19:40:39.972 NotebookApp] Loading IPython parallel extension
   [I 19:40:40.238 NotebookApp] [jupyter_nbextensions_configurator] enabled 0.2.4
   [I 19:40:40.242 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /notebooks
   [I 19:40:40.243 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
   [I 19:40:40.244 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/?token=89a3809bd589557e08e31d7fbd475e6e17bb333fe2311745
   [I 19:40:40.245 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
   [W 19:40:40.248 NotebookApp] No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.
   [C 19:40:40.250 NotebookApp] 

        Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
   to login with a token:
           http://localhost:8888/?token=89a3809bd589557e08e31d7fbd475e6e17bb333fe2311745
   ```

   but I have no access neither using browser on local device nor using http://`ip`:8888/ in local network

What I should do to make it work?

Comment: Did you try to visit the URL provided? Did you include the token? Is there any sort of firewall blocking acces to port 8888?

Comment: @ForceBru Yes, full url with the token, no additional firewall rules

Answer (score 0):

Try binding docker to all interfaces.

```
-p 0.0.0.0:8888:8888
```

Comment: Elinks said: Unable to retrieve http://localhost:8888/&token=....: Connection reset by peer

Comment: Are you trying to hit `localhost` on the NanoPi itself or on another machine?

Comment: on the NanoPi, this the reason why i'm worrying

Comment: try running Python's http server and see if you can hit that `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`. visit `http://localhost:8000`